# Firebase - Send notification using PHP not working right now

Tags: xcode

I am currently following the tutorial from this website: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

I am able to send notification from the firebase console but failed to do so from PHP

Comment: Please post some code, we cannot guess what you tried...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean to point out that you weren't able to receive the notification? If so, then this is probably because you were using a data message payload while your Android code is only handling notification message payloads. See Message Types for the description of both.

Push notifications coming from the Firebase Console are classified as notification message payloads. When you add in custom key-value pairs in the Advanced Options, it'll become a combination of both (notification and data in a single payload).

To handle data-only payloads, you'll have to use RemoteMessage.getData().